# Add Expires headers and image optimizaion not updating in siteground hosting

Tags: .htaccess, hosting

my website available in siteground hosting and i am updating **image optimization** as per suggestion **Gtmetrix** and **add expire header** but still not updating *it showing up old*

after i have also flush supercacher in hosting but still not updating

my expire header code like

```
############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/html A0
    ExpiresByType text/plain A0

</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 14 days"
ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 14 days"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 14 days"
ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 14 days"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 14 days"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 14 days"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 14 days"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 14 days"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 14 days"
ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/rss+xml "access plus 1 hour"
ExpiresByType application/atom+xml "access plus 1 hour"
</IfModule>
```

[image]

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My name is Georgi Ganchev and I am a Technical Support Supervisor at SiteGround.

I saw your thread and I decided to follow up.

The rules in your .htaccess are correct in general, but we recommend a longer expiration date set for your images, CSS and JS stored locally.

Please check the following article we have written about the most advised configuration:

https://www.siteground.com/kb/leverage-browser-caching/

In case the issue continues, please make sure you open a ticket through the User Area of your account with us and we will gladly help you out.

Best regards,
Georgi Ganchev
Technical Support Supervisor
Siteground.com

Answer (score 0):

We were trying to get a wrong result. i was searching for a solution too but what i found after reading the test result with those lines code and without them:

- this code is working but only with internal files.
- this code will not work with external files(from other websites like google analytics js ...).
- the test result will show you only the external files.
- if you remove those lines of codes the result will be worst, and it will result in more files doesn't have an expired age.